# How to get the selected item from list in a blackberry application

Tags: blackberry

How can i access the item selected from a list in one screen and pass it to another screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the selected row information by calling `listField.getSelectedIndex()` . This will return the selected row. Then you can get the value from the collections you have.

You have to implement `ListFieldCallback` interface and set the callback for the `listfield` by calling `listField.setCallback(ListFieldCallback callback)`. A `ListField` uses a class that implements the `ListFieldCallback` interface to perform drawing tasks. Then when a ListField must display an item in its list, it invokes the appropriate methods of the registered callback class.

check this example to know more about implementing listfield [Custom listfield](http://berrytutorials.blogspot.com/2009/11/create-custom-listfield-change.html)

Comment: final ObjectListField list = new ObjectListField();                        String[] items = new String[] { 1,2,3};                     list.set(items); add(list);      when i click '1' i have to go to next screen and display details for 1 and likewise for others. Any listener  for that?

Comment: Thank you for replying.I have read about navigation click does that handle list item click? This is my 1st experience with list so sorry for being silly.

Comment: You can handle navigationClick(). Inside that you can call getSelectedIndex() and you get the row in the list field.